Flush an OCaml formatter without resetting the pretty printer state
In the Format module, pp_print_flush writes the output to the formatter, AND resets the pretty printing state. Is it possible to flush, but not reset the state?
For example, creating a formatter with Format.make_formatter out flush, the out function is not called immediately when e.g. fprintf fmt ... is used. I want to trigger this call, but without resetting the pretty printer state, e.g. open boxes.
The problem
My system is a unit test framework where I want to support concurrent execution of tests. But the output should be such that the output for the tests is in the same order that the are started, and most certainly that output for different tests are not interleaved.
But I also want to output as soon as possible, so once "Test 1" is complete, its output is written immediate, but if "Test 3" is completed before "Test 1" and "Test 2", it's not written until the first two completes.
To verify this behavior I write a test that controls the order in which tests are completed, and verify the printed output after each task completion.
To help the tests, I made a formatter that appends to a string ref. But the out function is not called until pp_print_flush is called.
The make_string_ref_formatter:
let make_string_ref_formatter s =
  let out b p l =
    let current = !s in
    let appended = String.sub b p l in
    s := current ^ appended
  in
  Format.make_formatter out (fun _ -> ())

The test:
let s = ref "" in
let fmt = make_string_ref_formatter s in
let p1, r1 = Lwt.wait () in
let p2, r2 = Lwt.wait () in
let p3, r3 = Lwt.wait () in
(* Setup test functions for these delayed promises, and run the test runner ... *)
Lwt.wakeup r3 ();
!s |> should (equal_string "");
Lwt.wakeup r1 ();
(* The assertion fails if I don't flush the formatter here *)
Format.pp_print_flush fmt ();
!s |> should (equal_string "• ctx\n  ✔ 1\n  ");
Lwt.wakeup r2 ();
(* Flush is not necessary here, the test runner has completed and flushed *)
(* But the assertion fails because the boxes were reset, so the last item is not indented *)
!s |> should (equal_string "• ctx\n  ✔ 1\n  ✔ 2\n  ✔ 3");

So if the test doesn't flush, the output cannot be verified. But as the flushing closes the pretty printer boxes, indentation is off.
Right now, I've changed the expectation to match this undesired behavior, but I'd really like the test to describe the actual expected output.

First option: since you want an output by concurrent test, it is probably better to have a separate formatter by subtest. Then you can flush the formatter of the subtest when the subtest is done, and you don't have to worry about interleaving too.
For the second hackish option, an important point to keep in mind is that if there are no unknown size token in the printing queue, the Format formatting engine always prints to the low-level device directly. In other words, if one needs to flush to see the contents, the formatting engine was still trying to determine the size of the next token. This also means that one way to force the output is to set the current size of the printing queue to +infinity with
let large_size = 1_000_000 (*ideally Format.pp_infinity when available*) in
Format.pp_print_as ppf large_size ""

or
Format.fprintf ppf "@<1_000_000>%s" ""

which "prints" "" on the ppf formatter as if its size was large_size.
Minor remark: your make_string_ref_formatter is a less performant implementation of Formatter.formatter_of_buffer.

Thanks. Code didn't work with the %n option, but inlining the value in the format string did: Format.fprintf fmt "@<10000>%s" "";. I have no idea what "unknown size token in the printing queue" means, though ;) But my assertion now describes the expected output.
I did notice a formatter_of_buffer function - but was unsure if a buffer was static or dynamic in size. But this is not production code, this is only the test code for the library itself.
My tests are already generating separate printers, but this verification is about how they are eventually written to one combined output.

Ah yes, this was a mistake on my part: I forgot that @<> doesn't accept specifier contrarily to @[<...>. Fixed.
